# K-means clustering in R: normalizing DTM creates 'NaN'

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, tm

I have a corpus of documents that I created using the `tm` package and I made a document term matrix using the same package. I would like to use k-means clustering to cluster the documents. I use the Euclidian distance, so I first normalize the vectors so that Euclidian makes sense. However, when normalizing, it creates 'NaN' values for one specific document, and I don't know why. The code I use:

```
m = dtm
norm_eucl = function(m) m/apply(m, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) sum(x^2)^.5)
m_norm = norm_eucl(m)
cl = kmeans(m_norm, 2)
```

When I look at `m_norm`, it says (for example):

```
Terms     term1          term2
Docs
  1     0.2568640        0.8650674
  2     0.6204346        0.0000000
  3        NaN              NaN    
  4     0.0000000        0.6543098
```

So document 3 has 'NaN' values. Of course, when I try to use k-means, it throws the following error:

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Because it can't handle 'NaN' values. However, I don't understand why these 'NaN' values are created in the first place?

**EDIT:**
When I look at `apply(m, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) sum(x^2)^.5)` from the `norm_eucl` function above, the value for document 3 is zero. So it is trying to divide by zero, which is of course impossible. But does anyone know why this is zero and how to fix this so kmeans is still possible?

Comment: If document 3 has no terms in it then just remove it. As to why it has no terms, we'd have to see how you process your corpus and the data. Possible reasons: 1) only has sparse terms that get removed if you filter by sparsity. 2) only has stopwords, numbers and/or punctuation. 3) Was not read into the corpus correctly and ended up empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that document is *empty*?

Then it will have norm 0, and you get a NaN.

Check your preprocessing, but maybe just remove the bad document.